# ID3 Decision Tree with Numeric Values

Tags: python, id3, decision-tree

I'm looking for a ID3 decision tree implementation in Python or any languages which takes a validation and a testing file as an input and returns predictions.

I found [this](http://seat.massey.ac.nz/personal/s.r.marsland/Code/6/dtree.py) and this but I couldn't adapt them to numeric values, e.g. to [Iris dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris).

Do you know any ID3 tree implementation that works from console or any written in Python? Or any suggestion how to use [this](http://seat.massey.ac.nz/personal/s.r.marsland/Code/6/dtree.py) with numeric values will be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar algorithm C4.5 written in python. It work from console. If you are interested I put it here.

Sorry for a post if you need not this.

BTW, I have tested it on Iris data set :)

Update:

I have uploaded both: code and data:

- c4.5 - http://pastebin.ca/1802066
- iris.data - http://pastebin.ca/1802067

I hope it will help you.

BTW, program also can draw a tree into "png" via graphViz

Comment: Yes, I will appreciate if you can share C4.5 algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the C4.5 code. I need to calculate the accuracy of the classification. How can I get the predictic classes in your code? I tried to use classify(tree_root, ds) but it seems it returns the same class labels as the original -or I'm doing something wrong :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Labels are same because learning process are doing on whole iris data set. Just exclude some of data vectors from data file(or do it in 'load_iris' function), and use excluded vectors for testing predicting.